# maximum number of if-else and function call nesting allowed

Tags: function, if-statement, nested

Not so sure, if this question was asked earlier on SO. But, I didn't find answer and explanation.
I heard from many people that, interviewer asked question like :

1. How many If-else can be nested ?
2. How many function can be nested within function ?

I'm not sure about the answer and didn't find any explanation. In real time scenario I never got a chance to nest if-else condition more than 5-6. So, for the people who faced such questions, who never had such scenario where s/he had to use maximum number of nesting. How could they answer ? Any logic ? Does it also depends on language to language ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no virtual limit in nesting if-else statements.

But every time you call a function, the CPU has to save the current state in the stack. Sometimes the local variables are allocated in the stack too. Function arguments too are passed through stack some times. You go deeper in nesting functions, more and more memory you allocate in the stack. This leads the stack to overflow. How soon it will happen depends on what you allocate inside the functions.